# Why Google places api and google maps result are different?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm preparing a city guide application for android and in that I have added google places api so that the results will come from google. But When I search for places on google, how come the results are different?

For example, I was searching nashik road railway station and I found 4 photos available on the google maps, whereas there is not a single photo in my app(where i've used `google places api`).

Can anyone just clear out the things?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863598/android-how-to-display-photos-from-google-places-api

Comment: Most of the photos from google maps are content from panoramio or picasa, use their API's to request the photos